# USRP reference clock

Tags: gnuradio, usrp, uhd

At present I work with 2 different USRPs.

One of this is the USRP2 and the another one a newer device is the X300.

This devices communicate each about QPSK and a test algorithm.

The USRP2 has an output frequency shift of 20 kHz and make it impossible to
transmit narrow band signals.
Therefore, I use the reference clock output of the X300 to the USRP2.

To do this, I did use the command in python with GNU Radio

```
self.uhd_usrp_source.set_clock_source("external", uhd.ALL_MBOARDS)
```

Thereafter, the output signal shift is vanished, but my data hasn't been received by the X300.

Then I increased the master clock of 200 MHz of the USRP2:

```
self.uhd_usrp_source.set_clock_rate(200e6, uhd.ALL_MBOARDS)
```

In my opinion, the USRP2 don't supported this change of frequency.
My question would be:

1. Why is it not enough to set the reference clock to extern?
2. Why I don't receive data after this change to extern?
3. Why did solve the change of the master clock the problem?

Comment: Wait, do you have one uhd_usrp_source, or two? How do you select which USRP gets used by the uhd_usrp_source?

Comment: I use one USRP(X300) as transmiter and USRP2 as source.
The X300 received from the USRP2 acknowledgements, too.
But the devices get fixed different IPs and different PCs.
In python I use 
*self.uhd_usrp_source = uhd.usrp_source(*
         *device_addr=usrp_addr,...*